# How to bind MySQL 5.x to IP and localhost?

Tags: mysql

I need to connect to my MySQL Server from a remote source. Now I opened UFW to this IP and Port 3306. The next step is that I removed binding of 127.0.0.1 to that IP but then I can not connect from localhost. So I needed it to be 0.0.0.0

How can I bind MySQL to localhost and one specific IP?

Comment: Isn't it as simple as changing the `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: yes, but then it is open to the world (except that UFW is preventing it), I would feel more secure to have a double net, in case UFW failes/deactivates for what ever reason.

Comment: According to https://serverfault.com/questions/139323/how-to-bind-mysql-server-to-more-than-one-ip-address you can't bind to multiple IP addresses, but why should it be an issue? You can bind it to your "external" IP address and connect via that IP address. And for "localhost" it can use connection via a socket.

Comment: You could think about using your UFW rules to forward the outside connections for that one IP and Port to 127.0.0.1:3306 using a prerouting rule, then if UFW fails the connection from the outside would also fail. Depending on your current setup you would need to set `route_localnet` to `1` with `sysctl` for the corresponding adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You can, however, bind it to the one IP address that you want and access it locally through the socket instead of 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Hmm... that sounds like a plan. I somehow hold back as I don't want to change to much on the system. But yes, this might be a solution.